# Are dumbbell exercises counted in weight per side or total?

Tags: weightlifting, dumbbells

Bob does a set of dumbbell bench presses and is chatting with his mate in the locker room, comparing PRs. If Bob held one 16kg dumbbell in each hand, has he done a set of 16kg dumbbell benches, or rather 32? (Conventionally speaking)

Seems sensible to describe it as 32 for closest one may get to berbell parity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conventionally I mostly hear people say "16kg *dumbell**s***" as plural to denote that there is more than one. Though there is no standard. It could be different in different regions of the world. There is no governing body that determines how you say it.

If you're tracking then track whichever one you feel the most comfortable with and stay consistent with it.  If there's a competition of some kind then it should be clear in the rules of the given competition. If there's confusion in a conversation then I would hope it's easy to clear it up.

Comment: What do you think is more common for workout tracking?

Comment: @Seekinganswers  I don't know.  I track only the single dumbbell.  Someone who's more concerned with total weight moved may find it easier to track both.  There isn't any advantage or disadvantage to either.